# Thread - Violação de Acesso por Memória Compartilhada

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, concorrência

Eu utilizo uma biblioteca para recuperar os dados de uma Imagem (em unsigned char*), e utilizo ela para alocar em um Buffer (Textura) do OpenGL.

Como a imagem pode ser grande, o OpenGL por padrão cria uma outra thread para realizar essa atividade. Porém eu realizo free dessa imagem logo depois na thread principal, pois os dados não são mais necessários. **Daí eu recebo o *erro de violação de acesso* no endereço (Visual Studio).**

- O C++ tem algum recurso para para verificar se uma memória não está sendo utilizada por outra Thread Implícita (ou seja que eu não possuo acesso)?

Detalhes:

- A função que utilizo, que gera uma nova thread é glTexImage2D.
- O erro ocorre randomicamente, depende muito se a thread principal executar free antes do Opengl alocar no Buffer

Detalhes Técnicos:

*Exceção gerada em 0x07B8F54F (ig8icd32.dll) em ...[nomedoprograma.exe]: 0xC0000005: violação de acesso ao ler o local 0x13E1B000.*

O endereço 0x13E1B000 é null. Trecho do código como solicitado

```
int width, height, nrChannels;

unsigned char *dataImg = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
GLenum format;
if (nrChannels == 1)
    format = GL_RED;
else if (nrChannels == 3)
    format = GL_RGB;
else if (nrChannels == 4)
    format = GL_RGBA;

if (dataImg) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataImg);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
} else {
    log(StringBuilder::concat("STBI_LOAD::FAILED_TO_LOAD_IMAGE::", path));
}

stbi_image_free(dataImg);// <- ERRO AQUI
```

Comment: Não conheço soluções da linguagem para esse problema de concorrência que você colocou no ponto principal da pergunta. Mas há bibliotecas de concorrência que te ajudam a evitar isso. Semáforos e mutex são os que mais vejo em C. Talvez fosse interessante ler o que a documentação do compilador de C++ do Visual Studio tem a dizer sobre concorrência.

Comment: A hora não é propícia para chamar atenção, mas creio que dar um detalhe do excerto de código problemático, apresentando um [MCVE], possa gerar frutos quando mais usuários estiverem ativos. E conseguindo simular o seu problema também. Problemas de concorrência são [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). Ajudar a simular o problema consistentemente ajuda na solução

Comment: código adicionado, não sei se vai ajudar muito. Queria tornar o tópico mais amplo para problemas de memória compartilhada, não somente especifico do OpenGL.

Comment: Onde você viu que a função glTexImage2D gera uma nova thread, até onde eu conheço o OpenGL é inteiramente projetado para trabalhar em single Thread.

Tente mover o código 'stbi_image_free(dataImg);' para dentro do if (dataImg), se não existe a imagem não faz sentido liberar recurso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valeu pela dica nos comentários. 
Segundo a [documentação do OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes), glTexImage2D pode gerar erro durante a transferência se a imagem for de tamanho não divisível por 4.

> You create storage for a Texture and upload pixels to it with glTexImage2D (or similar functions, as appropriate to the type of texture). If your program crashes during the upload, or diagonal lines appear in the resulting image, this is because the alignment of each horizontal line of your pixel array is not multiple of 4. This typically happens to users loading an image that is of the RGB or BGR format (for example, 24 BPP images), depending on the source of your image data.